# Kafka Connect S3 Dynamic S3 Folder Structure Creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have [manually installed Confluent Kafka Connect S3](https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.1/connect/managing/install.html#connect-install-connectors) using the standalone method and not through Confluent's process or as part of the whole platform.

I can successfully launch the connector from the command line with the command:

```
./kafka_2.11-2.1.0/bin/connect-standalone.sh connect.properties s3-sink.properties
```

Topic CDC offsets from [AWS MSK](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/) can be seen being consumed. No errors are thrown. However, in AWS S3, no folder structure is created for new data and no JSON data is stored.

**Questions**

1. Should the connector dynamically create the folder structure as it
   sees the first JSON packet for a topic?
2. Other than configuring
   awscli credentials, connect.properties and s3-sink.properties are
   there any other settings that need to be set to properly connect to
   the S3 bucket?
3. Recommendations on install documentation more
   comprehensive than the standalone docs on the Confluent website? (linked above)

**connect.properties**

> bootstrap.servers=redacted:9092,redacted:9092,redacted:9092
>
> plugin.path=/plugins/kafka-connect-s3 key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>   value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>   key.converter.schemas.enable=false
>   value.converter.schemas.enable=false
>   internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>   internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
>   internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
>   internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
>   offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

**s3-sink.properties**

> name=s3-sink connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
>   tasks.max=1
>   topics=database_schema_topic1,database_schema_topic2,database_schema_topic3
>   s3.region=us-east-2 s3.bucket.name=databasekafka s3.part.size=5242880
>   flush.size=1 storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
>   format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
>   schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
>   partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
>   schema.compatibility=NONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should the connector dynamically create the folder structure as it sees the first JSON packet for a topic?**
Yes, even you control this path(directory structure) using parameter "topics.dir" and "path.format"

**Other than configuring awscli credentials, connect.properties and s3-sink.properties are there any other settings that need to be set to properly connect to the S3 bucket?**
By default, S3 connector will use Aws credentials (access id and secret key) through environment variables or credentials file.
You can change by modifying the parameter "s3.credentials.provider.class". Default value of the parameter is "DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"

**Recommendations on install documentation more comprehensive than the standalone docs on the Confluent website? (linked above)**
I recommend you to go with distributed mode as it provides high availability for your connect cluster and connectors running on it.
You can go through below documentation to configure connect cluster in distributed mode.
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide-dist-worker-config

Comment: What files would I find topics.dir, path.format and S3.credentials.provider.class in?

Comment: You have to pass these properties in your s3-sink.properties file.    https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/configuration_options.html